# Is writing about online games as freelancing halal?

Tags: halal-haram

I'm a freelance student and my job is to write about games, their features , about their specific missions etc. Is this halal or haram? Basically, I have to write the details of already available or in coming games in market.

Answer (score 1):

و عليكم السلام والرحمة الله وبركاته

There shouldn't be any problem with it as long the games are halal. There are various types of games. Combat games, adventure, educational, adult, gambling etc. If the games transgress the limits set by sharia then any act connected to them becomes haram. Example Gambling related games, adult games etc.

Answer (score -1):

Wa alaikumus-salaam,

I am not a scholar, but I think getting paid is meant for both halal and USEFUL activities.